# Need to access method/data from calling java methods

Tags: java

My challenge.   I have a class that is being accessed by third-party code, and I want to audit what's calling it.   To do this I need to access the object or at least the data of the calling objects.  Class name from the stack trace isn't far enough.

The real example:

I've extended the BaseStandardCredentials class from Jenkins.   I want to audit the `public Secret getPassword()` method.   But to audit, I need the job details.   Anyone using the more normal methods is audited elsewhere. But there are a few plugins/shared pipeline code which pull all credentials from the system, effectively hiding the job involved, and just cherry-pick the credential they need (http_request is the main culprit but there are others)

My basic thought is to audit the `getPassword()` function as that's exactly who/what is getting the data.  I can see in the stack trace the calling methods but that's no good if I can't get the job name/number from one of the execution objects.

Any way to do this? Or any way to at least tag the object in a way it shows up in a stack trace?

Comment: Please include actual code in a [REPREX]

Comment: Jenkins sets some environment variables like JOB_NAME or BUILD_URL when executing the jobs. Maybe you can get it from there?